# Selecting vector elements from dynamic indices using Specter

Tags: clojure, specter

I have a vector `[:a :b :c :d :e]` and some indices `[1 2 4]`.

Using Specter, how to select the elements of my vector from the indices, so that it returns `[:b :c :e]`?

Answer (score 4):

No need to use Specter:

```
(let [a [:a :b :c :d :e]
      B [1 2 4]]
    (mapv (partial nth a) B))
```

Or even simpler:

```
(let [a [:a :b :c :d :e]
      B [1 2 4]]
    (mapv a B))
```

But if you insist on using Specter, then here it is:

```
(let [a [:a :b :c :d :e]
      B [1 2 4]]
    (select (apply multi-path B) a))
```